# Sending Push Notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging API Client Library for .NET

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a .NET Web API and I want to send push notifications to my Android App. I have configured Firebase and am able to send to topic "foo-bar" using the legacy REST API Client. I now want to send images, which I believe is no longer supported in the legacy REST API.

I have created a console application and referenced Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1, but there seems to be little documentation on how to use it correctly.

```
I have created the following code, based on what I could glean at the Github repository (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/main/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1/Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1.cs)
```

```
static async Task PostMethod2()
        {
            BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "<MY_API_KEY>",
                ApplicationName = "<MY_PROJECT_NAME>"
            };

            FirebaseCloudMessagingService service = new FirebaseCloudMessagingService(initializer);

            ProjectsResource PR = new ProjectsResource(service);
            SendMessageRequest SMR = new SendMessageRequest()
            {
                Message = new Message()
                {
                    Topic = "foo-bar",
                    Notification = new Notification()
                    {
                        Title = "Sparky Says Hello!"
                    },
                    Android = new AndroidConfig()
                    {
                        Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                        {
                            Image = "<My Image URL>"
                        }
                    },
                    Apns = new ApnsConfig(),
                    Webpush = new WebpushConfig()
                }
            };

            SMR.Message.Apns.Payload = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            SMR.Message.Apns.Payload.Add("mutable-content", 1);
            SMR.Message.Webpush.Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            SMR.Message.Webpush.Headers.Add("image", "<My Image URL>");
            SendRequest SR = PR.Messages.Send(SMR, "projects/<My Project ID>");
            Console.WriteLine("Got Here");
        }
```

```
The debugger goes through each of the lines OK, but no notification appears. I have no visibility on the return result. Can someone please assist? Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to execute the send?

`var response = SR.Execute();`